# One who teaches reading comprehension is called what?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I googled everywhere but could not find even a single word for those who teach reading comprehension. However, I have just one guess about this: Reading Comprehension Teacher.

So what is the single word for those who teach reading comprehension?

Comment: 'anent' is archaic...no one uses it. Use 'about' instead.

Comment: hmmm ... a teacher?

Comment: The 'term' teacher does not specify any single service; a teacher may teach Biology, Physics, Chemistry, etc.

Comment: reading comprehension teacher, for all it's worth. Also, I don't associate teacher and service, particularly. If this is about teaching a language, there are four skills: reading,writing, speaking and listening.

Comment: Nobody teaches reading comprehension. If you teach reading, you teach reading comprehension.  Just like the people who teach English speaking; they also teach English listening comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Reading comprehension is generally taught as part of general instruction in a language; while it might be in a special module, there is to my knowledge no specialist term for this. I have spend about 25 years studying and working in the English departments of various universities, and have not come across such a term.

Often this is taught by *tutors*, who might be native speakers of a language but not fully qualified lecturers/teachers. But a *tutor* in that sense would be more like a junior teacher and they would also teach other areas, not just reading comprehension.

If you need to refer to such a person, *reading comprehension tutor/teacher* would not be a bad solution.

But otherwise: there is none.